# C# API get by id

Tags: c#

I am new in c#  and I am trying to implement an API that get a specific employee by id.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(int id)
{
    try
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM employees where id=@id"), con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            EmployeeModel employee = new EmployeeModel();
            employee.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            employee.name = reader.GetString(1);
            employee.surname = reader.GetString(2);
            employee.age = reader.GetInt32(3);
            employee.department_id = reader.GetInt32(4);
            return Ok(employee);
        }

        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

}
```

When I try to add breakpoints, at this row

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM employees where id=@id"), con);
```

it shows me cmd=null.
What should I do ??
Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem you run into is not really in the title. Put a breakpoint at the next statement (con.Open()), you will see the cmd object

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle it says {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because where you set your breakpoint in Visual Studio stops execution before that line gets executed.  If you advance (step forward) one more line, you will see your `cmd` populated.

Comment: But it returns me 400 Bad request. What should i do in this case??

Comment: If you are getting a 400 when executing just that one line of code, then it probably means there is something wrong with your connection string.

Comment: I am getting  400 when I execute this API. And I think the connection string works fine since I have tried ( put, post, delete) and they executed successfully.

Comment: Okay, I don't think that line of code is your culprit.  Try setting your breakpoint at `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, then using `F10` to step line by line.

Comment: Notice your own code is returning a "400 Bad Request" `return BadRequest()` explicitly whenever either some other Exception occurs, or when no data exists for that `id`.  So, you are essentially swallowing or hiding any potential underlying errors.